# argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I Have below two functions:

```
#To update the label1 if word is present with is_name
def update(data,word_lists, is_name):
 for wlist in word_lists:
    if check_keywords(data, wlist):
        return is_name
 return ''

#To check if Words are present in my Short_description field.
def check_keywords(data, words):
 cnt=0
 for word in words:
    if word in data:
        cnt+=1
 return cnt==len(words)
```

below is my data format:

> Short_description,  label1

These are the columns which i have in my data ACE_2017. 
i need to check for keywords in Short_description and update label1

Below is my update command:

```
#To check if "access request" or "request Access" is present in Short_description then it should update label1 with 'Access request'

ACE_2017.ix[ACE_2017['label1']=='','label1'] = ACE_2017[ACE_2017['label1']==''].Short_description.map(lambda x: update(x,[['access request','request Access']],'Access request'))
```

but when i run the above command it says

> argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

What am i missing here, how can i fix this.

Comment: i wrote an answer but it would also help to know what you're trying to do

Comment: updated my question with data and its purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this Issue is clear to you . "argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable" . in python if you try to iterate over a None type object then issue comes.

in your case every other parameter to function fixed except "short description" column value. which is changing with every iteration. check if "short description"  column contains any "NaN" value.!!